# Putty terminals hangs while trying to 'vi' files on Cisco anyConnect VPN

Tags: vpn, putty, vi, cisco

I am connected to my office VPN using Cisco Anyconnect client, from my home. I can putty to a remote machine. But , when I try to vi files, or execute a command such as netstat -an, the putty terminal just hangs. I can still open a duplicate putty session, but even it hangs as soon as  I execute certain commands, never to recover back.

Some commands like ls, uname -a works fine. My guess is that the terminal hangs when I try to vi (specially large file) or execute command which has large output.

If I connect to VPN from office, and then vi the same file, it works perfectly fine. My home network is a good speed broadband network. Also, if I connect to the same VPN using the same internet, same cisco-vpn client and vi the same file, from other laptop, it works fine!

Could someone provide some inputs on how this could be troubleshooted?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: okay, since I have got a reply here, will move it to super user along with the answer once I have a solution.

Comment: You can raise a custom moderator flag on your question, asking for the question to be migrated to Super User. This will preserve answers.

Comment: Flaged the question for migration to Super user, as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using the same user-id to login to the remote machine and there is no special scripts etc. present in the profile of the target machine (.bash_profile and similar files).

Few ideas -

1 - You may want to look into the putty configuration and see whether both the laptops have the same version and config setup for connecting to this server.

2 - Uninstall putty and re-install it. Otherwise download the latest version of putty and keep it at a different location to use it.

3 - Use ssh directly from windows in place of putty.

Some more info at this [link](https://community.hpe.com/t5/System-Administration/Telnet-session-hangs-when-I-open-vi-or-output-is-large/td-p/4242626)

Comment: I tried ssh in place of putty, and observed the same issue. Could the lptop memory play a role? The laptop on which I observe the issue is a 8GB RAM machine and dual boot. I am using same user-id to login to remote machine in both the cases

Comment: Local laptop memory should not be an issue here. It's the server which is really loading the file in memory. It can only be a network bandwidth problem. How about the commands like view <filename>, cat <filename> or less <filename>? Are they showing the content properly? You should try to use the head or tail command with the number of lines option - head -10 <filename>. Experiment with different numbers of lines, head -1, head -2 etc. and see when does the terminal starts hanging. Do you see the cursor and does it blink when vi is loading the file?

Comment: View<filename> also does not show any output. I tried tail -n <filename>. It displayed 27 lines and 28th line on wards the issue was seen. No, I do not see the cursor blinking when vi is loading the file

Comment: Also, if it were a bandwidth issue, how did vi work without any issue from the other laptop, which connected to same internet ?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new file, like "vi temp"? Probably that may work but if you open a file that has more lines than 27, it appears to be hung? What is the size of your terminal window? In both the laptops the resolution and terminal window sizes are same? Also try "\vi <filename>". There is a backslash appended in front of vi.

Comment: Added a link that indicates problem can be with the MTU setting on windows

Comment: Thanks sgarg so much!!. The MTU setting worked like a charm. That saved me a lot of trouble

Comment: That's great!! Happy that we could figure this out. It was a unique problem.